# generate unsigned ipa for ios with command line

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, react-native-flatlist, ipa

I use react native and want to make ios application out of it with help of CI/CD. We can make ipa for personal devices(not for upload on APPSTORE) free with xcode now i want automate same process with help of command line with ci/cd mac instance. I successfully made unsigned xcarchive file out of it now want that unsigned ipa with exportarchive command but it requires exportOptions.plist
which should have team id. I wanr unsigned ipa which will be later signed on.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the xarchive to zip and explore it it should contain an ipa.

Still I strongly suggest using Fastlane and signing your app directly.